# Generating an HTML page and save under a folder

Tags: php

I would like to make a form that once you insert data into the form, it will automatically create a html format of the data you entered in a html and save it in a folder! How do i go by doing this?

Comment: Where are you stuck ? You just need to generate your string and them save it in a file (using [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) for exemple)

Answer (score 3):

No idea what you mean by "html format of the data", but having PHP write a file is trivial:

```
$data = "your html format goes here";
$fh = fopen('the_file_you_want_to_write_to.html', 'wb') or die('unable to open file for output');
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
```

Or even more simplistically:

```
file_put_contents('the_file_you_want_to_write_to.html', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply place a wysiwyg html javascript editor (such as TinyMCE ) inside a form (textarea field), and store the output in a file with Php.

Some basic WIKI's do only that.